# Can I tag an interface when creating an instance using aws ec2 run-instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I want to tag an interface when I create an instance with multiple interfaces with AWS-CLI.

For example

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id {$byolimageid} --count 1 --instance-type c5.18xlarge --key-name thomaskeypair --network-interfaces '[ { "DeviceIndex": 0, "Groups": ["sg-06ec2ed1714b4b548"], "SubnetId": "subnet-0c36ed5c120    21bbb3", "DeleteOnTermination": true}, {"DeviceIndex": 1, "Groups": ["sg-06ec2ed1714b4b548"], "SubnetId": "subnet-011f43adb412986e0", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]
```

In this case, I want to tag interface with deviceindex 0 with a key,value.

Can I do it within the aws ec2 run-instances command?

Can't find information on documentation.